# Почему индекс не соответствует ожидаемому? (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Tags: java, android, массивы

Имеется 3 массива:

```
int[] A = new int[]{drawable1, drawable2, drawable3, drawable4, drawable5, drawable6};
int[] B = new int[]{drawable3, drawable4,};
int[] C = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

Данный код должен сравнивать первые 2 массива, если их элементы совпадают, то берет элемент из третьего с индексом равным первому и добавляет в ArrayList.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> checkArray(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list_C = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i : a) {
        for(int i1 : b) {
            if(a[i] == b[i1]) {
                list_C.add(c[i]);
            }
            //else {SG6Button1.setText("УРА!");}
        }
    }
    return list_C;
}
```

Возвращает: `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=2130839378`

Для меня не понятно, почему при длине 6, индекс такой большой?
Это из за того что элемент drawable?
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: Потому что `i` в данном случае не индекс элемента, а сам элемент

Comment: @Grundy можете подсказать как обратиться к элементу в данном случае?

Comment: просто прочтите в чем разница между for и for each, это и будет ответом на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При использовании [цикла for-each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) в случае

```
for(int i : a) {
    ...
}
```

`i` - Это не индекс элемента, а сам элемент. Поэтому код из вопроса судя по всему должен выглядеть примерно так

```
int index = 0;
for(int i : a) {
    for(int i1 : b) {
        if(i == i1) {
            list_C.add(c[index]);
        }
        //else {SG6Button1.setText("УРА!");}
    }
    index += 1;
}
```

Так как внутри for-each нет доступа к индексу, либо просто переписать на обычном `for`

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    for(int i1=0;i1<b.length;i1++) {
        if(a[i] == b[i1]) {
            list_C.add(c[i]);
        }
        //else {SG6Button1.setText("УРА!");}
    }
}
```